# UIToolbar has shadow during animation of pushing viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar, pushviewcontroller

I created a simple app and use the `NavigationViewController` as a initial view. I added a button on `navigationBar` and click it to push a new `UIViewController`. All of view controllers are simple and just set its background with UIColor.white, and the toolbar is enabled in `NavigationViewController`.

When I use `pushViewController` to switch a new one with animation, I found that there is some shadow below the `UIToolbar` during animating. Here is a snapshot:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20178358/39908537-1ecf8df6-5521-11e8-95ee-b22285d224c7.png

I tried to do like this:
1. In `viewDidLoad` of new `UIViewController`:

```
navigationController?.toolbar.isTranslucent = false
```

2. In `viewDidAppear` of new `UIViewController`:

```
navigationController?.toolbar.isTranslucent = true
```

There is no shadow under UIToolbar now during animating since the translucent is false and the toolbar is not blurred, after animation, I enable translucent but toolbar is dark now, see the snapshot:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20178358/39908525-12cbad46-5521-11e8-8678-4f553473f9f3.png

I don't know why the `ToolBar` is dark, but the `navigationBar` won't dark if I do the same steps on it.

Please help me how to do, or tell me where I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Try `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white` for the navigation bar shadow issue. 
Basically you need to change background color to white, for these kinda issues. I hope this helps.

Comment: Toolbar background issue could be fixed with 
`self.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.white`

Comment: @SatnamSync thanks, I tried but it doesn't work. I don't know what's wrong with my codes. I recreated the project and coded line by line again, seems the problem is dismissed. Thanks again.